# How to redirect to a specifi page of a view?

Tags: 8, forms, routes

Here is the code of a custom form:

```
  public function save(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $entity = $this->entity;
    $status = parent::save($form, $form_state);
    $values=$form_state->getValues();

some code here...

    switch ($status) {
      case SAVED_NEW:
        drupal_set_message($this->t('Le service « %label » a été ajouté.', [
          '%label' => $entity->label(),
        ]));
        break;

      default:
        drupal_set_message($this->t('Le service « %label » a été modifié.', [
          '%label' => $entity->label(),
        ]));
    }

    $form_state->setRedirect('view.services.page_2');
  }
```

The redirection doesn't work!
After validating my form, it goes to the first page of my view.
By the way, these two pages of the view are displayed as two tabs in a menu (the first being the default one)...

Comment: When you say page, do you mean page display or a page on a page display, e.g page 3 or the result set? the `view.services.page_2` route will take you to the `page_2` page display of the `services` view.  Are you saying this is not happening? It's taking you to the `page_1` page display of the `services` view?

Comment: You got it. It is exactly what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has two parts:
1. The button that takes to my form in 'Add' mode was coded this way: `<a href="/sel/service/add?destination=services" class="form-submit">Ajouter</a>` (/services being the first tab I mentioned).
So I removed the `?destination=services`
2. Looking at the 'Routes info' provided by Devel, I got that:
[image]
So i changed my code to `$form_state->setRedirect('view.services.page_2', ['arg_0' => $iSeliste]);`  (thanks to the last comment of [this page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirect/8.2.x)))

And now it works!